# Apple File Application perform "Move" action via file provider extension my extention display disable

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4, fileprovider-extension

[image]

[image]

In my file provider extension i want to perform move operation in my **NoteProvider** extension.

I can move any file via Drag operation above any folder it works properly But when i try to "Move" via Action display in bellow screen at that time screen2 display and other extension are enable but my **NotProvider** Extension was disable.

My code are `FileProviderItem`

```
class FileProviderItem: NSObject, NSFileProviderItem {

    public var id: String?
    public var name: String?
    var childItemCount : NSNumber?
    var documentSize: NSNumber?
    var creationDate : Date?
    var contentModificationDate : Date?
    var lastUsedDate: Date?
    var isDownloaded: Bool = false

    public var fTypeIdentifier: String?

    var pid : NSFileProviderItemIdentifier!

    var parentItemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier {
        return pid
    }

    var typeIdentifier: String {
        return fTypeIdentifier! // for folder =  "public.folder", for file  = file type UTI
    }

    var itemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier {
        return NSFileProviderItemIdentifier(self.id!)
    }

    var filename: String {
        return self.name!
    }

    override init() {

    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let obj = object as? FileProviderItem {
            if self.itemIdentifier == obj.itemIdentifier {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    var capabilities: NSFileProviderItemCapabilities {
        return .allowsAll
    }
}
```

For `FileProviderExtension`

```
class FileProviderExtension: NSFileProviderExtension {

 override func item(for identifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier) throws -> NSFileProviderItem {
    // resolve the given identifier to a record in the model
    // db = Array of NSFileProviderItem
    for i in db {
        if i.itemIdentifier.rawValue == identifier.rawValue {
            return i
        }
    }

    // TODO: implement the actual lookup
    throw NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSNotFound, userInfo:[:])
}

override func importDocument(at fileURL: URL, toParentItemIdentifier parentItemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier, completionHandler: @escaping (NSFileProviderItem?, Error?) -> Void) {

    print("importDocument :- \(fileURL) parentItemIdentifier = \(parentItemIdentifier)")
    completionHandler(nil, nil)
 }

 override func reparentItem(withIdentifier itemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier, toParentItemWithIdentifier parentItemIdentifier: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier, newName: String?, completionHandler: @escaping (NSFileProviderItem?, Error?) -> Void) {

        print("reparentItem :- \(itemIdentifier) parentItemIdentifier = \(parentItemIdentifier) newName = \(String(describing: newName))")

        guard let item = try? item(for: itemIdentifier) as? FileProviderItem else {
            completionHandler(nil, NSFileProviderError(.noSuchItem))
            return
        }

        item?.pid = NSFileProviderItemIdentifier(rawValue: parentItemIdentifier.rawValue)
        //item?.name = newName
        completionHandler(item, nil)

    }
```

}

NoteProvider(FileProvider) .plist file image
[image]

Comment: I would recommend overriding the method importDocument, but I couldn't test it.

Comment: i have tried but this method was not called

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya can you share plist ?

Comment: @MAhipalSingh you want file provider extension plist file ?

Comment: @MAhipalSingh question updated

Comment: Can you pls try these keys 
 UIFileSharingEnabled  = true and 
  
LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace = true .

NSExtensionFileProviderSupportsEnumeration = true

Comment: @MAhipalSingh Thanks,i have tried but it not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return **NSFileProviderItem** instance in **itemForIdentifier** method for identifier **NSFileProviderRootContainerItemIdentifier**. If you return nil for root identifier, app wont be enabled in move operation.

Comment: i have updated my question can you please reffers it

Comment: i am exiting to know that where you have read this? is there any documentation or Blog ?

Comment: Was having same issue. Couldn't find much info on detailed FileProvider implementation. Tried many ways to enable my Provider with MOVE, succeeded with this. Trailed by assuming to provide valid root to get detected by Files browser.

Comment: can you please check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783317/apple-fileprovider-extention-in-file-application-remove-copy-duplicate-operatio